# How to remove empty lines from xml to CSV output in XSLT3.0

Tags: xml, csv, text, xslt-3.0

I have XML data which I have transformed using XSLT from XML to output csv formatted text. It generates the output when the filter condition is met. I now need the code to stop producing any output when filter condition not met. Currently it generates header when the filter condition is not met.

I tried setting global variable but none seemed to work with 2 templates being used.

```
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:param name="xslt.transform.params"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="countryCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="$xslt.transform.params"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <csv:columns>
        <column>ORIG</column>
        <column>CUST</column>
        <column>PARTY</column>
        <column>ACCOUNT1</column>
        <column>ACCOUNT2</column>
        <column>CURRENCY</column>
        <column>SUM1</column>
        <column>SUM2</column>
        <column>SUM3</column>
        <column>SUM4</column>
        <column>SUM5</column>
        <column>SUM6</column>
        <column>SUM7</column>
        <column>SUM8</column>
        <column>SUM9</column>
        <column>SUM10</column>
        <column>SUM11</column>
        <column>SUM12</column>
    </csv:columns>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/DATA/G">
        <xsl:variable name="result" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="orgsysref" select="ORIG"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
            <xsl:variable name="vCountry" select="fn:substring($orgsysref,1,2)"/>
            <xsl:if test="$vCountry = fn:substring-before($countryCode,'|') or $vCountry = fn:substring-after($countryCode, '|') or $vCountry = $countryCode">
                <xsl:variable name="column" select="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="value" select="$result/*[name() = $column]"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input message:

```
<DATA>
    <G>
        <ORIG>test107015196</ORIG>
        <CUST>30AB00000197776</CUST>
        <PARTY>customer</PARTY>
        <ACCOUNT1>0432007015196</ACCOUNT1>
        <ACCOUNT2>Customer</ACCOUNT2>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <SUM1>440.26</SUM1>
        <SUM2>3</SUM2>
        <SUM3>0</SUM3>
        <SUM4>0</SUM4>
        <SUM5>16.66</SUM5>
        <SUM6>1</SUM6>
        <SUM7>423.6</SUM7>
        <SUM8>2</SUM8>
        <SUM9>0</SUM9>
        <SUM10>0</SUM10>
        <SUM11>0</SUM11>
        <SUM12>0</SUM12>
    </G>
    <G>
        <ORIG>test106438731</ORIG>
        <CUST>3000KJ3324638</CUST>
        <PARTY>Distrißüter</PARTY>
        <ACCOUNT1>04910438731</ACCOUNT1>
        <ACCOUNT2>Distrißüter</ACCOUNT2>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <SUM1>312.18</SUM1>
        <SUM2>1</SUM2>
        <SUM3>0</SUM3>
        <SUM4>0</SUM4>
        <SUM5>312.18</SUM5>
        <SUM6>1</SUM6>
        <SUM7>0</SUM7>
        <SUM8>0</SUM8>
        <SUM9>0</SUM9>
        <SUM10>0</SUM10>
        <SUM11>0</SUM11>
        <SUM12>0</SUM12>
    </G>
    <G>
        <ORIG>test203084024</ORIG>
        <CUST>30XY0013478518</CUST>
        <PARTY>Test UAT DE</PARTY>
        <ACCOUNT1>0492003f084024</ACCOUNT1>
        <ACCOUNT2>Testing UAT DE</ACCOUNT2>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <SUM1>2745.79</SUM1>
        <SUM2>12</SUM2>
        <SUM3>0</SUM3>
        <SUM4>0</SUM4>
        <SUM5>2751.68</SUM5>
        <SUM6>11</SUM6>
        <SUM7>-5.89</SUM7>
        <SUM8>1</SUM8>
        <SUM9>0</SUM9>
        <SUM10>0</SUM10>
        <SUM11>0</SUM11>
        <SUM12>0</SUM12>
    </G>
</DATA>
```

Actual result:

```
ORIG,CUST,PARTY,ACCOUNT1,ACCOUNT2,CURRENCY,SUM1,SUM2,SUM3,SUM4,SUM5,SUM6,SUM7,SUM8,SUM9,SUM10,SUM11,SUM12
```

Expected result: no output with any headers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` into the `xsl:if` and change the nesting, wrap the `<xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">` into the `xsl:if`, it looks to me as if the `test="$vCountry = fn:substring-before($countryCode,'|') or $vCountry = fn:substring-after($countryCode, '|') or $vCountry = $countryCode"` does not in any way depend on the value of that `for-each`.

In the end the whole code looks like XSLT 1 instead of using XSLT 2 or 3 features (like variables of type `xs:string*`, comparison with `=` simply in the pattern or apply-templates, `xsl:value-of separator` to output comma separated values).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have taken your feedback into consideration and will refine the code. Last question please: I also need to stop producing any output when the country condition is not met. meaning: If i filter for test2 as country code, there should not be any output produced. Currently, it generates the header irrespective of the filter criteria. How do i stop generating the header when there is no relevant country (test2) match?

Comment: @pitsa, consider to ask that as a new question if you can't figure it out, you should be able to write a test expression selecting downwards in the template matching `/` or in a global variable and use it. And please include a small but representative XML sample of the XML you have if further problems arise.

Comment: refer this for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696345/how-to-remove-headers-and-produce-no-output-when-specific-condition-is-not-met

Answer (score 0):

You're doing work inside the per-column loop that could be done outside it, and fixing this would solve the problem:

```
<xsl:template match="/DATA/G">
        <xsl:variable name="result" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="orgsysref" select="ORIG"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vCountry" select="fn:substring($orgsysref,1,2)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$vCountry = fn:substring-before($countryCode,'|') or $vCountry = fn:substring-after($countryCode, '|') or $vCountry = $countryCode">
            <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
                <xsl:variable name="column" select="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="value" select="$result/*[name() = $column]"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
             </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Note how the newline is now output within the conditional.

As a bonus, a couple of comments on your code:

(a) It's more efficient to output a delimiter before every item other than the first, rather than after every item other than the last. That's because it doesn't involve lookahead (evaluation of `last()`), so it doesn't disturb pipelined evaluation. Some processors of course will optimize this for you anyway.

(b) using document('') to access the stylesheet at run-time is a pretty awful hangover from XSLT 1.0. It's much better to put the data in a global variable. With document(''), (i) the source stylesheet has to be available at execution time, not just at compile time, and (ii) you have to read it twice, because the rules for whitespace stripping in source documents are different from those in stylesheets.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable feedback. I also need to stop producing any output when the country condition is not met. meaning: If i filter for test2 as country code, there should not be any output produced. Currently, it generates the header irrespective of the filter criteria. How do i stop generating the header when there is no relevant country (test2) match?

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions in comments. Either add to your original question if it's just more detail on the question, or raise a new question if that's what it is.

Comment: I have updated my original question as suggested. Please assist. Thank you.